# Ghost blog, Error while running it on local machine

Tags: node.js, localhost, openshift, ghost

I have installed ghost blog on Openshift and created local copy to make some changes. I added new theme and deployed it back to openshift. Its working fine but I am not able to run this blog on my local machine.
If I run NPM start, I am getting following error:

```
> openshift-ghost-quickstart@ start C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean
> node index

Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v47-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Client_SQLite3.initDriver (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:41:24)
    at new Client_SQLite3 (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\sqlite3\index.js:15:10)
    at Knex.initialize (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\knex\knex.js:109:15)
    at Knex (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\knex\knex.js:13:26)
    at ConfigManager.set (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\core\server\config\index.js:156:24)
    at ConfigManager.init (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\core\server\config\index.js:79:10)
    at C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\core\server\config\index.js:273:30
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:507:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:581:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\darklord\OneDrive\Business\mean\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:697:14)
```

I though that this errpr has something to do with sqlite3 so I have uninstalled and installed it back but still same error.

Can someone let me know what mistake I am going ?

Comment: Maybe there is an issue because your local machine is on windows?  I sometimes have that problem with some python packages

Answer (score 0):

In case other people are running into this issue.

You are probably running a different node.js version on your local machine.

You could check manually in the `{gostblog}\node_modules\ghost\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\` folder if you have a different version than the `node-v47-win32-x64` he is asking for.

Just reinstall the Ghost dependencies on your local machine to get it running.